# Showing $|a_k | \le 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

Let $A$ be the closed unit disk $A= \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| \le 1 \}$. Suppose $f$ is an entire function whose Taylor series centered at the origin is $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_kz^k$$ and that $f$ maps $A$ into $A$. Show that $|a_k | \le 1$ for each $k$.

Do I have to use a ratio test to show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: use the integral formulation of Taylor coefficients.

Comment: ...I just researched it..saw a few variations...which do you suggest?

Comment: Not sure what your variations are, but I'm suggesting "The Taylor coefficients $a_k$ of $f(z)$ at $0$ are equal to the integral of $\frac {f(z)}{z^{k+1}}$ along a contour about $0$". Choose an appropriate contour and approximate with what you know.

Comment: Flipping through the pages of my complex analysis book, I'm not finding this. I do find a way which my book does a similar example using Weierstrass M test

Comment: @User69127: It's difficult for us to know what you know and what you don't. You've not done Cauchy's Theorem and the Cauchy integral formula? If not, what are you proposing? I don't see the ratio test or Weierstrass M-test as being helpful.

Comment: Yes sorry are you talking about $f(z_0)=\frac {1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}$? I guess I don't know how to go about this problem using this @TedShifrin

Comment: @User69127 That's one - but it'll only tell you about the first coefficient ($f(0)$). There should be a more general version you can attack this problem with - that gives you either Taylor coefficients, or the values of derivatives.

Comment: Yes i found one under the laurent expansion section. $a_n=\frac {1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(tilda)}{(tilda-z_0)^{n+1}}$ not sure how to write the tilda

Comment: I've seen these formulas but even if I did see the formula, how do I approach it? Will you show me which formula you are suggesting? Thank you.

Comment: That's the one you want to use :) $z_0=0$, and you'll be able to bound both the top and bottom as having absolute value $\leq 1$ with your hypotheses and an appropriate contour.

Comment: ohhh ok! Thanks for the guidance! I'll try it

Comment: @Mike what is tilda in my case?

Comment: @User69127 What you call tilda is just a variable they used to integrate it. You could call it z or x or whatever you want.

Comment: Great! Next issue: approximating. Less than or equal to... @Mike

Comment: @User69127 Last thing I'll say: take your integral along the boundary of the unit disc, and use the fact that $f(z) \in A$, and that $z \in A \implies |z| \leq 1$